Gibbs Free Energy, Temperature and Equilibrium
I was recently taught one of the Gibbs Free Energy formulas, where the change in Gibbs Free Energy is related to the change in enthalpy and entropy
∆G = ∆H - T∆S,
and that the system is at equilibrium when ∆G = 0. Wouldn't this imply that the system only reaches equilibrium at one specific temperature? I know that can't be correct, but am struggling to relate that knowledge to what the equation states. Is it possible for the system to not have a ∆G = 0 at equilibrium?
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

I will probably write an answer later, but as for now, you need to consider that $\Delta H$ is not generally independent on temperature! See for example the definition of the heat capacity in thermodynamics. This means that, generally speaking, as long as you do not fix the temperature with a thermostat, you can reach an set of equilibrium conditions strongly dependent on the other state variables. It is not possible to have $\Delta G \neq 0$ in equilibrium, actually this is an equivalent definition of thermodynamic equilibrium, this does not mean that the system cannot reach a steady state.

@GiuseppeBasile Thank you very much! If ΔH is dependent on temperature, does that mean that questions like 'at what temperature will the system reach equilibrium' are not valid, as the ΔH value provided would only be valid at one temperature? And what is the difference between an equilibrium state and a steady state? Thanks!

The point is that, eventually, at any temperature that you fix with a thermostat, your system will reach an equilibrium state, meaning one at which the free energy is minimized. Equilibrium means that your system does not experience any kind of possible spontaneous transformation without being strongly perturbed. So, in equilibrium there should not be  any kind of matter or energy flows, let alone direct chemical reactions or similar processes. A steady state, on the other hand, is just a particular state of the system whichm if unperturbed retains its property over time.

This means that the system can be in a state that does not minimize free energy (at costant temperature and pressure) but still be in a steady state.

@GiuseppeBasile With regards to your second comment, would any system reach equilibrium if left at a fixed temperature? I was under the impression that if the entropy change was negative and the reaction was endothermic, it could never reach an equilibrium as ΔG≠0 for all values of T

Again, you were assuming the entropy and enthalpy does not change - in either value or sign.
